# Unable to create a class with name Entry

Tags: java, hashmap, naming

Following code fails compilation with error  following error message :

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Test1.Entry to
>   Map.Entry

My question is can't we ever use class with name `Entry` in our project while using `hash map` ? And why this error is there though i did not import any  `Entry` class here.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
public class Test1 {

    public static class Entry<T> {
        public String m() {
            return "A";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Set<Entry> a = new HashSet<>();

        new HashMap<String, Entry>() {
            {
                for (final Entry entry : a) {
                    put(entry.m(), entry);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can keep this class name and code compiles successfully.

Comment: resolve the imports issues

Comment: No i did not use any imports. let me add edit question as put imports as well

Comment: That compiles with Jdk 1.7 for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Since you are using [double brace initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java) the maps internals are exposed in that block.**

Either rename the `Entry` class or move the initialization code out of the init block of the `HashMap` so your `Entry` does not shadow the maps internal `Entry` implementation.

```
final HashMap<String, Entry> map = new HashMap<>();
for (final Entry entry : a) {
   map.put(entry.m(), entry);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a issue with the names:

your `Entry<T>` is shadowing at some point the `java.util.Map.Entry<K, V>`

just rename the Entry to something else

```
public static class MyEntry<T> {
    public String m() {
        return "A";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the compiler that you want to use Entry interface provided by java.util.

As you already have a class named `Entry` in the same package in which you are using it hence it is implicitly imported. For all the places where you intent to use `Entry` from java.util you have to explicitly use `java.util.Map.Entry` instead of just `Entry`. This way you can use both the classes.

Answer (score 0):

This snapshot might clear your doubt,

[image]

As error popup states, the compiler is thinking that Inside your for loop it's java.util.Map.Entry but you want to traverse over your custom `Entry` class over here.

Even though you assume that you aren't importing `java.util.Map.Entry`,  Try removing 1st import (i.e. HashMap) and you will see that you are no longer getting Incompatible Types Error.

You can try any of the suggested workarounds to get rid of this problem.